# jquery - Can you manipulate page titles?

Tags: jquery, parameters, title

I thought I heard somewhere that you couldn't use jquery to manipulate the  content...  Is that correct?  Basically, I have a site that has parameters like p.php?d=keyword+keyword+keyword, and I wanted to be able to set the title according to what's in that d parameter...  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why don’t you do that with PHP?

Comment: I agree it would be more logical to that on the server.

Comment: Maybe he's doing some sort of AJAXy thingy and he wants the title to keep up with the current page-state. Admittedly it's a weird thing to do, but ...?

Comment: Make sure you escape the d parameter though. You don't want anyone setting d to: </title><iframe src="www.bad-site.com" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('title').text("some text");
```

Comment: this won't work in IE6 or older Firefox versions (3.0). use document.title.

Answer (score 15):

You dont need jQuery for this:

```
document.title = 'Some text';
```

Comment: @cobbal Completely disagree. Its better to do what is efficient. Creating a new jQuery object (`$()`), calling an un-scoped `title` search across an entire document, then calling an additional function to set the title is much less efficient than referencing an existing object's property. This is the better way.

Comment: I would argue that by that logic you never need jQuery. Also, I don't foresee page title changing to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it on the client side with JavaScript/jQuery, try this:

```
// get query arguments
var $_GET = {},
    args = location.search.substr(1).split(/&/);
for (var i=0; i<args.length; ++i) {
    var tmp = args[i].split(/=/);
    if (tmp[0] != "") {
        $_GET[decodeURI(tmp[0])] = decodeURI(tmp.slice(1).join(""));
    }
}

// change title of document
if (typeof $_GET["d"] == "string") {
    $("title").text($_GET["d"]);
}
```

Comment: to much code for a tiny problem that can be solved using document.title